# Form Based Authentication in a JAVA Web Application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication

I wanted to get some more information on about form based authentication. I understand that the form based authentication mechanism is used when you want to protect certain server resources, like all jsps under a certain directory, and only make those URL's available to users with certain roles.

I am working on an application from scratch, just to get better at web development, and I have the form based authentication setup, and it is working fine. However, I would also like to build in the ability for users to login on the fly, using a 'Login' button, not just when they necessarily try to access a protected resource.

I know that when I tried to have the login button take the user to the login page that uses j_security_check as its action, the server yelled because I was directly accessing the login page, which makes sense because since I wasn't trying to access a protected resource, so I guess the server wouldn't know where to take me after I authenticate.

So, my question is, if I want to keep the form based authentication in place to protect some admin resources, but also have the ability for the user to just login on the fly using a login button, do I have to roll my own security, and have the form take me to a servlet(for example) that manually checks the username and password against the database, and set some attribute that says whether or not the user is logged in? How would that mesh with the server knowing whether or not I'm logged in? I know that there are some server side methods for getting the user, asking if they are in a certain role, etc, but isn't that all server managed, meaning I can't just say 'hey, I've authenticated the user myself, and this is who they are, it has to go through the form based authentication? I'm still learning web development. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  I'm using JEE container security in Glassfish 4 with form based authentication.  I have a login.xhtml page that is not protected.  I can display a link to that page if I am not logged in.  I don't need to attempt to visit a protected page.  Is that not what you are trying to do?

Comment: Not quite. The issue was that with form based authentication, the login page is only triggered when you try to access a protected resource, like an admin directory. If I provide a login button myself to allow the user to login whenever they want, I can't use the same login mechanism (j_security_check), because I haven't tried to access a protected resource. Basically, only the app server can use and display the login page (and that happens when the user tries to access a protected resource)

Comment: But you can just browse to the login page.  At least, you should be able to.  I can in my app.

Comment: If the form in your login page has an action that points to "j_security_check", and you have MANUALLY navigated to the login page without being prompted to login because you tried to access a protected resource, I don't see how that will work. I've figured out a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of providing the behavior that you want is through a cookie that doesn't expire easy, which has its [fair share of security concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking). It seems you want to have the ease of use that the "Login with Google", or "Login with Facebook" have. These tend to make heavy use of something called OAuth, and I don't think are applicable for your project.

Are you forced to login for a resource every single time you access it? You shouldn't be , as you seem to be using the servlet's form authenicator.